# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' while merging two sorted Linked Lists in Python

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote a function to merge two sorted linked lists in Python. Here's the code :-

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        last_node = self.head
        while last_node.next is not None:
            last_node = last_node.next
        last_node.next = new_node
    
    def print(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next is not None:
            print(cur_node.data, "-> ", end='')
            cur_node = cur_node.next
        print(cur_node.data)

def merge(l1, l2):
    cur_node1 = l1.head
    cur_node2 = l2.head
    l3 = LinkedList()
    while cur_node1.next is not None or cur_node2.next is not None:
        if cur_node1.data > cur_node2.data:
            l3.append(cur_node2.data)
            cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
        else:
            l3.append(cur_node1.data)
            cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
    if cur_node1.next is None:
        l3.append(cur_node1.data)
        while cur_node2.next is not None:
            l3.append(cur_node2.data)
            cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
        l3.append(cur_node2.data)
    elif cur_node2.next is None:
        l3.append(cur_node2.data)
        while cur_node1.next is not None:
            l3.append(cur_node1.data)
            cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
        l3.append(cur_node1.data)
    return l3


ll1 = LinkedList()
ll2 = LinkedList()
ll1.append(12)
ll1.append(45)
ll1.append(69)
ll1.append(70)
ll2.append(1)
ll2.append(2)
ll2.append(99)
ll2.append(100)
ll3 = merge(ll1, ll2)
ll3.print()
```

But after running the code I got this error  `File "C:/Users/_/PycharmProjects/DAA/SinglyLinkedList.py", line 179, in <module> ll3 = merge(ll1, ll2) File "C:/Users/_/PycharmProjects/DAA/SinglyLinkedList.py", line 143, in merge while (cur_node1.next is not None or cur_node1 is not None) or (cur_node2.next is not None or cur_node2 is not None): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'`

What's going on here? I don't get it. I tried running the code without the or statement in the while loop in the merge function. It worked fine. So apparently the problem is in the while statement. Can somebody help out?

Comment: I think you want that check to be `cur_node1 and cur_node2`, since the first thing you do inside the loop accesses both `cur_node1.data` and `cur_node2.data`.  Not sure if that will be enough to make the merge work correctly; it might be an indication that you've failed to account for an edge case.

Comment: Consider the case where `cur_node1 is None`. Do you expect `cur_node1.next is not None or cur_node1 is not None` to evaluate successfully? Why? How?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely not enough -- your initial while loop will walk off the end of one list or the other, so the code after that needs to be able to handle the case where at least one of the two nodes is `None`.

Comment: I made cur_node1 the pointer for the first linked list and cur_node2 the pointer for the second linked list. Now I compared the data in the particular nodes I traversed in the two linked lists. If some particular data is smaller, I append it to the newly created list, l3. Now if we reach the end of one linked list while comparing, we should be out of the while loop. cur_node1 will never be None because when cur_node1 is the pointer to the last node in list1, cur_node1.next becomes None so it will break out of the while loop in the next iteration. The or operator is causing problems.

Comment: Lmao, nevermind. I just changed the `while` loop to `while True:` and put the conditions inside the loop. If the conditions (`cur_node1.next is not None or cur_node2.next is not None`) are met, I just break out of the loop. Works great now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in your first loop:

```
while cur_node1.next is not None or cur_node2.next is not None:
```

This means that one of the two nodes could have `next` attribute that is `None`. If then also that node has data that is less than the data in the other node, then this node variable will be set to `None`. Then the `while` condition is evaluated again, and produces an error, as this `None` value has no `next` property...

You are actually overcomplicating the algorithm by checking that the `cur_nodeX.next` attribute is `None` instead of `cur_nodeX` itself. By consequence you need to still add nodes from both lists *after* the first loop has finished. Moreover, your code assumes that both lists are not empty.

So, make your `while` condition based on the current nodes, and not on their `next` properties:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    cur_node1 = l1.head
    cur_node2 = l2.head
    l3 = LinkedList()
    while cur_node1 is not None or cur_node2 is not None:
        if cur_node1 is None or cur_node2 is not None and cur_node1.data > cur_node2.data:
            l3.append(cur_node2.data)
            cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
        else:
            l3.append(cur_node1.data)
            cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
    return l3
```

Comment: Your code only works if we assume iterating through l1 finishes first. I'm getting this error if `cur_node2` becomes `None` first - `if cur_node1 is None or cur_node1.data > cur_node2.data:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: Indeed. Fixed now.

Comment: Nice. Pretty clean code. I need to learn how to write like that lol.

Answer (score 0):

This print '1 -> 2 -> 12 -> 45 -> 69 -> 70 -> 99 -> 100'

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    cur_node1 = l1.head
    cur_node2 = l2.head
    l3 = LinkedList()
    while cur_node1 and (cur_node1.next is not None or cur_node2.next is not None):
        if cur_node1.data > cur_node2.data:
            l3.append(cur_node2.data)
            cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
        else:
            l3.append(cur_node1.data)
            cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
        if cur_node1.next is None:
           l3.append(cur_node1.data)
           while cur_node2.next is not None:
               l3.append(cur_node2.data)
               cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
           l3.append(cur_node2.data)
        elif cur_node2.next is not None:
            l3.append(cur_node2.data)
            while cur_node1.next is not None:
                l3.append(cur_node1.data)
                cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
            l3.append(cur_node1.data)
    return l3
```

Comment: The expected result is "1 -> 2 -> 12 -> 45 -> 69 -> 70 -> 99 -> 100"

Comment: It's ok now, there was a problem of indentation

Answer (score 0):

For anybody wondering, this works.

```
def merge(l1, l2):
cur_node1 = l1.head
cur_node2 = l2.head
l3 = LinkedList()
while True:
    if cur_node1 is None:
        while cur_node2.next is not None:
            l3.append(cur_node2.data)
            cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
        l3.append(cur_node2.data)
        break
    elif cur_node2 is None:
        while cur_node1.next is not None:
            l3.append(cur_node1.data)
            cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
        l3.append(cur_node1.data)
        break
    if cur_node1.data > cur_node2.data:
        l3.append(cur_node2.data)
        cur_node2 = cur_node2.next
    elif cur_node1.data < cur_node2.data:
        l3.append(cur_node1.data)
        cur_node1 = cur_node1.next
return l3
```